# getting a 404 page for all pages except home. possibly permalinks

Tags: customization, permalinks

I can switch to default and everything works, but once permalinks is set i get the 404. The thing is I've been using permalinks for years without problems. I can't find what went wrong as I had not made any changes in weeks. It happened all of a sudden.

I tried finding the .htaccess (showing hidden files) but to no avail.

Does wordpress update itself perhaps? I notice there's an admin bar at the top of my page when logged in...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your permalinks will work without the .htaccess file. If you create a blank one, set the permissions to 777 and try to update your permalinks again, WordPress should automatically add the rules. Then be sure to change the permissions back!

Comment: toss it where the index.php file is?

Comment: Usually in the root folder of your site, or the root of your WordPress installation, depending on how it's installed. Here's some info on [wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Where.27s_my_.htaccess_file.3F) about permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in the root directory of your Wordpress install (where the index.php etc is) and set it to what WP tells you to when you turn permalinks on.

Comment: in the wp-content folder... the prompt just says permalinks structure update. It's so weird because it happened out of the blue.